# Why does my code display rubbish?

Tags: assembly, x86

My code is display rubbish when I want to print each of the numbers in the list as well, anything wrong? The output should look like this:

THE GIVEN ARRAY IS:2G;4?PT **why is this rubbish**
THE TOTAL NUMBER IS:7

**Code**

```
ASSUME  CS:CODE , DS : DATA, SS: STK
ORG 0000H

DATA SEGMENT
  LIST DB 2,23,11,4,15,32,"$"    ; Given Array with last element $ to indicate end 
MESSAGE1    db "THE GIVEN ARRAY IS:$"   ;message 1  
MESSAGE2    db "THE TOTAL NUMBER IS:$"  ;message 2  
DATA ENDS

;stack segment  
STK SEGMENT STACK  
DB  512 DUP (?)  
TOS LABEL   WORD  
STK ENDS  

; code segment  
CODE SEGMENT    
    ORG 2000H

START :  
MOV DX, DATA  
MOV DS, DX  
MOV DX, STK  
MOV SS, DX  
MOV SP, OFFSET TOS  
XOR AX, AX                  ; Clear register  
XOR BX, BX                  ; Initialise index register  

LEA DX, MESSAGE1  
MOV AH, 9h
INT 21H

LEA SI , list

MOV CL,0  
MOV AL,"$"   

AGAIN:   
CMP AL,[SI]  ; look for end of list  
JE over  
MOV DL, LIST[BX]                ; Move array numbers      
ADD DX, 30H      ; convert number to character.  
MOV AH, 2                   ;display the number at the screen  
INT 21H  

INC SI  
INC BX
INC CL
Jmp AGAIN       

over:    
LEA DX, MESSAGE2  
MOV AH, 9h  
INT 21H  

PUSH CX           ; transfer cl to dl for int21/ah=2.  
POP DX  
ADD DX, 30H      ; convert number to character.  
MOV AH, 02H      ; prints the character in dl.  
INT 21H  
MOV AH, 4CH      ; exit.  
INT 21H  

CODE ENDS    
END START
```

I think I knew why already whatever the number greater than 10 it will display as character, but how to let it display in number like "13" dont display as "="?

Comment: This code need reformatting! Is this an homework? Don't use tabs by the way.

Comment: It needs lowercase. There's enough shouting in the world already.

Comment: I already fixed this code once. Why did you roll back my edits? If you expect to get some help here, learn to use the formatting features or at least accept the help from other users who do.

Answer (score 6):

```
LIST DB 2,23,11,4,15,32,"$"
```

You are not realizing that the values over 9 consists of more than one numeral. That's why the values 2 and 4 come out correct; you display the "2nd" and "4th" number characters, but there is no character for number 23. You need to display that number as 2 *and* 3.

What you need is a proper **int to string** function to output the values as ascii.